# Export Mailbox to PST Every Month through PS

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which suppose to export previous 30 day mailbox from the current date. But it always exports complete mailbox, it ignores the content filter.

```
$mailbox = "psingh"

$FromDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

$FromDate = "'$($FromDate)'"

New-MailboxExportRequest -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $FromDate) -or (Sent -ge $FromDate)} -Mailbox $mailbox -FilePath "\\FileServer\EmailBackups\ExportTest\MonthTest2\Singh, Paramjot.pst"

Write-Host "Done."
```

Please help me correct this code

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good; but your date converstion looks complex and risks using a date format that's different to what your server expects.  Instead, try just using the date as is:

```
$mailbox = "psingh"
$FromDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
New-MailboxExportRequest `
    -ContentFilter {(Received -ge $FromDate) -or (Sent -ge $FromDate)} `
    -Mailbox $mailbox `
    -FilePath "\\FileServer\EmailBackups\ExportTest\MonthTest2\Singh, Paramjot.pst"
Write-Host "Done."
```

Per [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff601762(v=exchg.150).aspx), those fields are DateTimes; so converting from DateTime to string just adds risk without benefit.

**More Info**

I think you've based your code on an example where someone's hardcoded the date; e.g. `(Received -ge '01/01/2015')`.
Based on this you've tried to get your `$FromDate` variable to hold `'01/01/2015'`.  However, the quotes around the date are there for syntactic purposes; i.e. to say "what's contained within is a value.  When you have a variable, it already knows it's contents / value; so we don't need to put the quotes into the value itself.  Additionally, the hardcoded version uses a string representation because it's easy to write and is automatically converted to a datetime.  The parameter is defined as accepting a DateTime, and `get-date` returns a DateTime; so you don't need any conversion logic.

i.e. your code is effectively: `-ContentFilter {(Received -ge "'01/01/2015'") -or (Sent -ge "'01/01/2015'")}`

...as opposed to: `-ContentFilter {(Received -ge '01/01/2015') -or (Sent -ge '01/01/2015')}`

I'm a bit surprised you're not seeing a `Cannot convert value "'MM/dd/yyyy'" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."` error; do you have errors suppressed?

To see this error, run the following `[datetime]$dt = "'01/01/2015'"`

I hope that helps to better explain things; please let me know if this explanation isn't clear and I'll try to reword appropriately.

Comment: FYI... See here for a full explanation of everything.  The part he's missing is some of the syntax is from dynamically built commands with PS where the string is concatenated to a command that is run.  Also, even though the -ContentFilter switch documentation states DateTime for the data type, for some reason is does not work unless it's formatted in `MM/dd/yyyy` format which is not what `Get-Date` outputs. If you see my answer in this link, it may all make better sense though.  http://superuser.com/questions/1011308/power-shell-script-to-export-mailbox/1011877#comment1404715_1011877

Comment: Actually the documentation states that `Date-Time stamp` is the value and not that Date-Time is the data type... Maybe that's why it doesn't work as expected.  In either case, I wanted to point that out just in case but see my above comment and that post for all the full detail from SU where the first part of this question was posted.